# azure リソースマネージャでVMのサイズ変更を行いたい

Tags: azure, powershell

AzureでVMを作成し、powershellにてVMのサイズ変更を行うスクリプトを作っています。
クラシックならサイズ変更のコマンドがあるのですが、リソースマネージャにてサイズ変更を行う事はできないでしょうか？

Get-commandで「"*size*"」を引数にして検索してもリソースマネージャのコマンドは見つかりませんでした。
まだこのコマンドは実装されていないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

わかりやすいコマンドはまだ実装されてないようです。
実際に変更するにはこんな感じになるかと思います。

```
$VMName = "2007CMCEN"
$NewVMSize = "Standard_A5"

$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VMName
$vm.HardwareProfile.vmSize = $NewVMSize
Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VM $vm
```

参考URL： http://blogs.technet.com/b/mmodin/archive/2015/12/01/resize-azure-arm-virtual-machine-with-powershell.aspx